# How do I use php?=

Tags: php

I'm kind of a noob at this stuff.

But I've been browsing around and I see sites that are kind alike this

```
www.store.com/product.php?id=123
```

this is really cool. but How do I do it?

Im stuck using something like this

```
www.store.com/product/product123.php
```

If you could tell me how I can go about do this it would be awesome!

Comment: you want to rewrite your url ?? or want to fetch parameter from the url ???

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is a `$_GET` argument.

In your PHP code, try writing something like this:

`$value = $_GET['foo'];`

Then open your page like this:

`hello.php?foo=123`

This will set `$value` to `123`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `$_GET` here.

if you use the following:

```
?id=123
```

then this will be how to use it and the result

```
$_GET['id'] (returns the 123)
```

You can use as many `$_GET` arguments as you need, for example:

```
?id=123&foo=bar&type=product
```

`$_GET` is an array of what parameters are in the url, so you use it the same way as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called URL parameters (what they're contained in is called a query string), and they're not unique to PHP but can be accessed in PHP using the [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Similarly, you can get POST parameters using the `$_POST` superglobal, though in POST requests, [these parameters are not appended to the URL](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/).

Note: Generally, for usability purposes (and thus also SEO purposes), you want to avoid using query strings as much as possible. These days, the standard practice is to use URL rewriting to display friendly URLs to the user. So your application might accept a URL like:

```
/products.php?id=32
```

But the user only sees:

```
/product/32
```

You can do this by using `mod_rewrite` or similar URL rewriting capabilities to turn the friendly URL into the former query string URL internally, without having the user type out the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `product.php` with this code:

```
<?php
echo "The argument you passed was: " . $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Now run this URL in your browser:

```
http://<yourdomain>/product.php?id=123
```

and you will understand how $_GET works.

Comment: I'd suggest using `<pre><?php var_dump($_GET) ?></pre>`. This will also allow the user to experiment with passing arrays to PHP via GET parameters, which is non-standard.

Comment: Okay, I get this now, thanks. But how would I take them to product123 page when they type ?id=123 in?

Comment: @user1495292: Are you sure that it is what you want to do? If yes, you could do something like: `if($_GET['id']==123) header("Location: path/to/product123.php");` Note that you can mark an answer as solved when you think the answer is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the documentation at www.php.net, especially these pages: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Specifically, have a look at **$_GET** and **$_POST**, which are two frequently used ways to transmit information from a browser to the server. (In short, GET-parameters are specified in the URL, as in your question, while POST-parameters are "hidden from view", but can contain more data - typically the contents of forms etc, such as the textbox you posted your question in).